# Zend DB Expr getting values from previous join

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following code in a zend db query

```
->join(array('z' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $this->_dbhInstance->select()->from('zipcode', array('lat', 'lon', 'zip'))
                    ->group('zip') . ')')), 'zip = f.zipcode')
        ->join(array('distance' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT GetDistance(' . $lat . ',' . $lon . ',z.lat,z.lon) as distance)')))
```

The issue is that z.lat,z.lon is not getting the values from the previous join (>join(array('z'), it just uses the actual text.

How can I format z.lat,z.lon) to grab the values from >join(array('z' ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because Join has tree parameter

```
->join(tableName,joinCondition,fetchParameters)
```

but you have wrote only two...